# Lightning Record Form not working for custom objects in communities

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, custom-object, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-sets

There is a custome object called CutomObject in my sandbox system. I have created a salesforce community to display these objects.

I have created a sharing set on this object type as follows and granted `read/write` access.

`CustomObject.Account = User.Contact.Account`

This works fine so that, When I query all the CustomObjects it only extract relevant records. My lightning web component has a model containing following code to view entire CustomObject. (This model appears on abuttonClick)

```
<lightning-record-form
    record-id="xxxxxxxxxxx"
    object-api-name="CustomObject__c"
    layout-type="Full"
    mode="readonly"
    columns=2>
</lightning-record-form>
```

But it is not execute properly. Following error appears.

`You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS`

[image]

Please note that this error only appears when I log in as a community user. When I log in as the system admin user this is working fine.

Any clue for this?

Comment: Check if you have given objects access and FLS to Community User Profile. AS you are having account lookup on CustomObject you will need Read Access on Account Object and Account Name field.

Comment: I found the issue behind this. With my sharing set, the user is granted only access for that set of records. But when I check the object privileges of the user's profile, it was indicated as `no access` against my CustomObject. Once the read access is granted, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the user does not have permission to access the particular record type. To enable,

- Type and **profiles** in SETUP
- Then select the profile related to your community.
- Select **Object Settings** under **Apps**
- Change **Object Permissions** of CustomObject__c to Read from No Access.

Now you are able to use `lightning-record-form`.

Answer (score 0):

This took me some hours, I thought I'd post the answer here to see if it helps anyone:

1. My custom objects didn't allow me to check the checkbox above directly when  I access profile > object settings as stated by another answer in this post.
   [image: Can't check checkbox at the top]
2. So, I slot in permission set to check the settings above - then I assigned it to the user.
   [image: Creating a new permission set]
3. Then, I do a sharing set to match the custom object field to user profile's email:
   [image]
   [image]

After all the above steps, it can now show up when using lightning component in community/experience cloud.